# Graph that using BFS to find Cycles

Tags: java, file, arraylist, graph, breadth-first-search

I wrote this code that should find a cycle by reading a text file that shows debts between people. So "person1,person2,amount" meaning the person1 owes person2 the amount of dollars. I need to create a method that finds a cycle between the people in the file. So if the file holds this information: Paul,Jesse,50
Jesse,Leo,75
Leo,Paul,100
The cycle could be [Paul, Jesse, Leo], [Jesse, Leo, Paul], or [Leo, Paul, Jesse] and the cycle amount would be 50.

I have tests that test to make sure that the order of the cycle is correct and when I run the test it says that there is only two people in the cycle when there should be 3 and also it says that the cycle amount is -50 when it should be 50. Im not good at using the debugger so I didn't get much information from that.

Here is some information that could help:

The findCycle method that takes no parameters and returns a reference to a Cycle object using the provided Cycle class. This method will detect if there is a cycle in the debt data and will return it if it exists. A cycle exists if there's any number of people all of whom owe money to the next person in a way the eventually returns to the original debtor. The amount of the cycle is the minimum amount owed throughout the cycle. If such a cycle exists, the amount of each debt in the cycle could be reduced by the cycle amount (You don't have to reduce the debts, just detect the cycle). For example, if Paul owes Jesse $50, Jesse owes Leo $75, and Leo owes Paul $100, there there is a cycle [Paul, Jesse, Leo] of $50
If no cycle exists, the method returns null
If a cycle exists, return a Cycle object containing the names of everyone in the cycle in the order in which they appear, and the cycle amount. Note that the starting point is ambiguous so your tests must accept any valid ordering. In the example above, there three valid orderings [Paul, Jesse, Leo], [Jesse, Leo, Paul], and [Leo, Paul, Jesse]
You may assume that there is at most 1 cycle in and file of data and your test cases should contain at most 1 cycle
A cycle can be as small as 2 nodes (eg. 2 people owe each other money)
Hint: If you run BFS and find an edge leading to the starting node, you just found a cycle

Here is my code:

```
package money;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class DebtCalculator {
    private Map<String, Integer> debts;


    public DebtCalculator(String filename){
        debts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        try {
            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename)));
            for (String line : lines) {
                ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
                String person1 = fields.get(0);
                String person2 = fields.get(1);
                int amount = Integer.parseInt(fields.get(2));
                int existingDebt = debts.getOrDefault(person1, 0);
                debts.put(person1, existingDebt - amount);
                int existingCredit = debts.getOrDefault(person2, 0);
                debts.put(person2, existingCredit + amount);
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public int netGains(String person) {
        return debts.getOrDefault(person, 0);
    }

    public Cycle findCycle() {
        Map<String, String> parents = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, Integer> cycleAmounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Queue<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
        for (String person : debts.keySet()) {
            parents.put(person, null);
            cycleAmounts.put(person, 0);
            queue.add(person);
        }
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            String person1 = queue.poll();
            int amount1 = debts.get(person1);
            for (String person2 : debts.keySet()) {
                if (person1.equals(person2)) {
                    continue;
                }
                int amount2 = debts.get(person2);
                int amount12 = Math.min(amount1, - amount2);
                int newAmount1 = amount1 - amount12;
                int newAmount2 = amount2 + amount12;
                if (newAmount1 == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (parents.get(person2) == null) {
                    parents.put(person2, person1);
                    cycleAmounts.put(person2, amount12);
                    queue.add(person2);
                } else if (parents.get(person2).equals(person1)) {
                    ArrayList<String> peopleInCycle = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String person = person2;
                    int cycleAmount = cycleAmounts.get(person);
                    while (!person.equals(person1)) {
                        peopleInCycle.add(person);
                        person = parents.get(person);
                        cycleAmount = Math.min(cycleAmount, cycleAmounts.get(person));
                    }
                    peopleInCycle.add(person1);
                    // return the first cycle found
                    return new Cycle(peopleInCycle, cycleAmount);
                }
            }
        }
        // no cycle found
        return null;
    }
}
package money;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cycle {

    private ArrayList<String> peopleInCycle;
    private int cycleAmount;

    public Cycle(ArrayList<String> peopleInCycle, int cycleAmount) {
        this.peopleInCycle = peopleInCycle;
        this.cycleAmount = cycleAmount;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPeopleInCycle() {
        return this.peopleInCycle;
    }

    public void setPeopleInCycle(ArrayList<String> peopleInCycle) {
        this.peopleInCycle = peopleInCycle;
    }

    public int getCycleAmount() {
        return this.cycleAmount;
    }

    public void setCycleAmount(int cycleAmount) {
        this.cycleAmount = cycleAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: "there is only two people in the cycle"  Which person is missing?  If the first or last person is missing you probably have an error in initializing are finishing the  code loop

Comment: The person that is missing is Jesse. It is only adding Leo and Paul in that order. It should go either  [Paul, Jesse, Leo], [Jesse, Leo, Paul], or [Leo, Paul, Jesse] these are all valid.